# Multi Date selector in Asp.Net Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Asp.net Calendar .if I select one date change the color for selected Date .but I select more than one date selected dates color is not retained. How to solve problem?

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calDate" runat="server" SelectedDayStyle-BackColor="DarkBlue"  selectionmode="DayWeekMonth"
        selectorstyle-font-bold="True" selectorStyle-backcolor="#3366ff"
        font-name="Tahoma" font-size="12" backcolor="ivory"        
        selecteddaystyle-font-bold="True" OnDayRender="calDate_DayRender"  OnSelectionChanged="calDate_SelectionChanged" >


protected void calDate_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Day.IsSelected)
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Orange;

}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear with the question or can you please share a glimpse of your code

Comment: Yeah, which calendar? Have you considered it may be one that does not support it? It is it system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar then - use nother one. One that does exatly this (support multi select).

Comment: What you have tried till now? Provide some code!

Comment: The control has the feature to select week, month etc. I dont know if it allows selecting non-contiguous range of date. Take a look at `SelectionMode` property -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Did my answer work for you. Can you mark as answered if it did please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the presumption that you are using the ASP.net inbuilt calendar control.

You will need to keep track of the selected dates. One way of doing this would be to use the Session. Another could be the ViewState etc. Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
public static List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

protected void calDate_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
        {
            list.Add(e.Day.Date);
            e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
        Session["SelectedDates"] = list;
}


protected void calDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
        {
            List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
            foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
            {
                calDate.SelectedDates.Add(dt);
            }
            list.Clear();
        }
}
```